# Change image background when page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the background full image on div id="img" to change whenever the page is reloaded, can this be done on pure css or javascript is required?. Here is my http://jsfiddle.net/9Dp2e/ I am using javascript with jquery to change the background image randomly, but I doesn't work using the code below, any help would be appreciated.

```
Here is my html:
<div id="header">
<ul>
<div id="wrapper">
  <li class="logo"></li>
  <li>Homes</li>
  <li>Offices</li>
  <li>Products</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  </div>
</ul>

</div>
<div id="center">
<div id="slider">





<div id='footercopy'>

<p>Copyright 2014 &nbsp<a href=""></a></p>

</div>




<div id="img">

<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Flaming_cocktails.jpg">

</div>


</body>
</html>

Here is my css:
html,body
{
height:100%;
}
body
{
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}
h1
{
font-size:30px;
}
#img
{
 position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#img img
{
 position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
#center
{
position:relative;
z-index:10;
top:0;
min-height:1000px;
background:white;
width:960px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
min-height:1000px;
padding:20px;
}
#header
{
position:relative;
z-index:20;
color:white;
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:1700px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:-10px;
background:silver;
opacity:0.7;
}
#wrapper
{
width:960px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
}
#header li
{
display:inline;
padding-right:20px;
}
.logo
{
font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
font-size:30px;
color:blue;
}

/*content*/
#content
{
padding-top:80px;
width:500px;
}
.floatLeft 
{ 
float:left;
margin: 4px; 

}
.floatRight 
{ 
float: right; 
margin: 4px; 
}
#content img
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
padding:20px;
}
.width
{
width:250px;
padding:10px 30px;
}
#sidebar
{
margin-top:50px;
float:right;
min-height:1500px;
text-align:center;
}
#sidebar img
{
width:150px;
height:150px;
}
#sidebar li
{
list-style:none;
padding:10px;

}
#content-right
{
padding-top:80px;
width:450px;
float:right;
}
#content-right img
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
padding:20px;
}

Here is my javascript:
var images = ['http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg', 'http://images.china.cn/attachement/jpg/site1007/20130621/0013729929f1132dee4303.jpg', ];
$('#header').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
$('<img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '">').appendTo('#img');
```

Comment: Its possible only with JS !

Comment: The css and img bit makes no sense. Your randomisation code works but I don't understand what you actually want to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this... Works Perfectly fine. Just made it up :)

This one is without jQuery. No need to load the heavy script in your page :)

```
//You can increase the images by adding more links to the array 
var array = ['http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg','http://images.china.cn/attachement/jpg/site1007/20130621/0013729929f1132dee4303.jpg'];
function shuffle(array) {
var currentIndex = array.length;
var temporaryValue;
var randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return array;
}
var shuffled_images = shuffle(array);
var yourbackground = document.getElementById('img');
yourbackground.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + shuffled_images[0] + ')' ;
```

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/kakashihatake2/9Dp2e/5/ (To make this work, you need to remove the `<img src="Cocktails Image" />` from `<div id="img">` ) :)

Answer (score 1):

**[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/9Dp2e/3/)** it was working with your logic , just add jquery in fiddle and increase the number of images and removed the unwanted  just to check.

`Math.random()` between 1 and 0, will have less probability to act like random since we have only two values

Comment: Beat me too it. At last some sense! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial: http://briancray.com/2009/12/28/simple-image-randomizer-jquery/

1. Start with an array of images.
   Change the image filenames in the array to the actual filenames. Don't include the directory—filenames only.

   ```
   <i>This is not italic</i>, and [this is not a link](http://example.com)var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg'];
   ```
2. Set a random  background with jQuery and CSS background-image

   ```
   $('#body').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Using :**
Here ,you have to use,

`Math.random()` with in `Math.round()` because,`Math.round()` figures your returning value to 0 and 1,so if you have only two images then `Math.round()` performed them well,and *may not* repeat any background more then once.

```
var images = ['http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg', 'http://images.china.cn/attachement/jpg/site1007/20130621/0013729929f1132dee4303.jpg', ];
var random = Math.round((Math.random()*images.length))

$('#background').css({'background-image':images[random]})
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to bind 'beforeunload':

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){
    /* change background */
});
```

How can you do this reading image from array of images?

- read cookie value (a counter): if there is no value, save in it 0 value.
- read images[count]
- on 'beforeunload' save in coockie count+1 (if count > images.length -> count=0)

Comment: First of all the question is about plain Javascript, not jQuery, second it is useless to use cookies in this case

Comment: first of all "[..]I am using javascript with jquery to change the background[..]"

Comment: second "[..]any help would be appreciated[..]". This is any.

Comment: btw ok, maybe is not THE solution, but certainly not -2

Comment: none of this is relevant. adding before unload will have zero affect.